# Interface builder warning (but works fine)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a warning that is annoying me. Everything works fine, but I would like to know why it's giving me this warning and how I can get rid of it.

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UIScrollView`. I've set it like this:

[image]

I set the text in the UILabel at runtime dynamically. I think that is because the `UILabel` has no text in it right now (at compile time) so it thinks it's width and height needs to be 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: No, this is not because your label has no text. it's must be about your constrants

Answer (score 1):

In IB, if you move / resize a view that is positioned by constraints, the constraints don't change, so now what you see is not what you'll get when the app runs. That is what "Misplaced View" refers to. To fix it, tell IB to match the constraints to the frame or the frame to the constraints, depending which one you want.

In your case, you want the constraints to match the frame. Otherwise, when the app runs, your label will have zero height and zero width.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the misplacement by clicking on the warning triangle.

You will get a pop out dialog with a bunch of radio buttons on.

I normally just go for `Update Frame`

W

Comment: I'll choose Update Constraints for this case.

Comment: Update constraints has no effect.